# pass data through attribute in a directive to access it in compile phase?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to access a object in the directive at compile phase. since compile phase do not provide scope. and attrs.data will return a string so what can be best way to get the data.

**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h2>MainCtrl</h2>
        {{data}}

        <div dir data="data.items">
        </div>
      </body>
```

**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "first"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "second"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "third" 
    }]
  }
})

.directive('dir', function() {
  return {

    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A', 
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
              //need to access $scope.data defined in MainCtrl.
      });
    }

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Isolate scope is a good pattern to bind the data from parent scope

```
<div dir data="data.items">
```

and provide it to directive's `link` or `controller` like that

```
angular.module('app').directive('dir', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    ...
  }
})
```

Or you can use one-way binding

```
<div dir data="{{data.items}}">
```

to get it in `link` function `attrs.data`. That's how Angular expects it to be done.

Your question itself describes what's going on during compile phase. You can't access the scope, and

```
<div dir data="{{data.items}}">
```

won't help either because the attributes in `attrs` aren't interpolated in `compile` function. There is a reason why it doesn't work like that: `MainCtrl` runs *after* directive's `compile`.

Answer (score 0):

The partition of the rendering process into a compile and a link phase is a cornerstone in the angular framework. This construction means you get the chance to fiddle with your template before it gets 'instantiated' with scope data in the link phase.

The compile callback of a directive runs just once - while the link callbacks may run any number of times with different scopes.

So what to do if the template you want to pass to angular depends on some data you have in your application? Once your directive is registered with angular, its template is immutable.

We can't use the scope - so what I do is to have a javascript object - let's call it a registry - which lives outside of the angular context. I then put the data I need access to from the compile phase into the registry and pass the key into the compile phase via attributes in the template, which you do have access to in the compile phase.

Care needs to be taken to not leak memory when this approach is used. Possibly by having a $destroy callback which cleans out the appropriate registry entries.

Answer (score -1):

Lets little hack `compile` so we can have access to `scope`

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('app', function($scope) {
    this.data = {
      items: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "first"
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "second"
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "third"
      }]
    }
  })
  .directive('dir', function() {
    return {
      replace: true,
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        data: '='
      },
      compile: function(element) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          alert(JSON.stringify(element.scope().ctrl.data))
        }, 1)
      }
    }
  })

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="app as ctrl">
  <div dir data="ctrl.data.items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The pre and post properties you return from the compile callback are what make up the link phase though - so no scope access in the compile phase.

Comment: Your change to using setTimeout simply serves to delay scope access until after the compile phase - so again - no scope access in the compile phase :) Also, using element.scope() means your directive will only work when angular is running in debug mode.